Placing Shadowed Titles within a Tikzpicture
I am trying to adapt the excellent answer of Sandy G found in Arching a Shadowed Title to a slightly different problem.
Consider the code:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\definecolor{PureGold}{RGB}{255,215,0}
\definecolor{PrussianGreen}{RGB}{14,108,55}
 
\tikzset{
    mydecor/.style={line width=9mm, PrussianGreen,
        postaction={decorate, decoration={text along path, text align=center, raise=-1.8ex, text={|\color{black}\bfseries\sffamily\LARGE\,|#1}}}, 
        postaction={decorate, decoration={text along path, text align=center, raise=-1.5ex, text={|\color{PureGold}\bfseries\sffamily\LARGE\,|#1}}}
}}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[mydecor=PRUSSIAN GREEN] (180:3.05)arc(180:0:3.05);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\vspace{15pt}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[mydecor=PRUSSIAN GREEN] (0,0)rectangle(7,1); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}

which produces the output:

It is not clear to me why the command \draw[mydecor=PRUSSIAN GREEN] (0,0)rectangle(7,1); within a tikzpicture environment does not produce the shadowed title "Prussian Green" nicely centered within the said picture. Basically, I would like to "unbend" the arch and shorten it a little to display a green rectangle with the shadowed title centered within.
QUESTION: Can someone point out my error and suggest a correction? I am compiling with pdflatex.
Thank you.

If you don't want the text to bend, why not use a simple node?

The my decor style centers the text along the path. Your path starts and ends at (0,0), with midpoint at (7,1), so it is centered.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I made several attempts with that route, but to no avail, as the mydecor would not act as "simple text" which is easily handled with \node.

@DDS With simple I meant without decorations. See my answer below.

If you don't need to bend the text, using decoration seems overly complicated. You could use simple nodes instead:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\definecolor{PureGold}{RGB}{255,215,0}
\definecolor{PrussianGreen}{RGB}{14,108,55}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill=PrussianGreen,font=\bfseries\sffamily\LARGE\color{black},inner sep=3ex] (foo) {Prussian Green};
\node[font=\bfseries\sffamily\LARGE\color{PureGold}] at ([shift={(-0.3ex,0.3ex)}]foo) {Prussian Green};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



This works quite nicely; thank you.

@DDS You're welcome!

The style my decor draws the text centered in the given path, and also draws the style of the path to be 9mm wide and Prussian Green. You could just fill the rectangle, followed by a path with the text:

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\definecolor{PureGold}{RGB}{255,215,0}
\definecolor{PrussianGreen}{RGB}{14,108,55}
 
\tikzset{
    mydecor/.style={
        postaction={decorate, decoration={text along path, text align=center, raise=-1.8ex, text={|\color{black}\bfseries\sffamily\LARGE\,|#1}}}, 
        postaction={decorate, decoration={text along path, text align=center, raise=-1.5ex, text={|\color{PureGold}\bfseries\sffamily\LARGE\,|#1}}}
}}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=9mm, PrussianGreen, mydecor=PRUSSIAN GREEN] (180:3.05)arc(180:0:3.05);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\vspace{15pt}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[PrussianGreen] (0,0)rectangle(7,1); 
\path[mydecor=PRUSSIAN GREEN](0,.5)--(7,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}


Many thanks Sandy G.; however. I was hoping that "Prussian Green" would be centered where the white line segment (I can't figure out why it's there) currently is.  I have noticed that if I increase line width=9mm to, say, 19mm, the white line disappears  completely---which is what I want, but the title is still not perfectly centered in the green box.   So, how may we remove the white line and center the title in say, the current box? Thanks again.

@DDS: updated my answer.

Many thanks Sandy G.
